# How can I get the value from a multidimentional array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, cmd, active-directory

I am trying to pull some file paths from an array and use them to test if a folder is located on serval machines.
I seem to get an error pulling the value from the 2-dimentional array and putting it in a variable.

Here is a striped down, very basic version of my script.

```
$PCS = "PC1","PC2","PC3"

$locations=     @("System32","Windows\System32"),
                 ("Public","Users\Public")


ForEach($PC in $PCS){



$i=0
Do
{

$fullpath = "\\" + $PC + "\C$\" + "$locations[$i][1]"
test-path $fullpath
$i++
}

While ($i -le ($locations.length-1) )





}
```

However when I use $fullpath to test if the folder is there, I get false, and upon further investigation, the actual value of $fullpath is:

```
 \\PC1\C$\System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[]
```

How can I get the value from the array, so I can use it as a filepath location?

Comment: You're attempting to access `$locations[$i]` but you're never setting `$i`

Comment: Thanks arco444 - I missed a part of the initial code, sorry! It's been added now, thanks

Comment: I have a hard time believing the do-while loop even starts, let alone, yields results: it's based on $location which is not defined. And even if you added the missing 's', it's `$location.count`. And why making a two-dimensional array is all you look at, is the `[1]` value. A single dimension would have been enough. Also, the title of your question has a typo.

Comment: Clearly it was a typo of "$locations"...updated. Thanks.
EDIT: The reason for a two dimentional array is because I use the [0] Value in another part of the full code, and this is just a snippet, but regardless my question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```powershell
$fullpath = "\\" + $PC + "\C$\" + "$($locations[$i][1])"
```

or

```powershell
$fullpath = "\\" + $PC + "\C$\" + $locations[$i][1]
```

As arco444 points out, your code as posted seems incomplete, but I think your issue will be fixed by above.

### Explanation

When you use `"$locations[$i][1]"` it only interprets `$locations` as a variable within the string. Using `.` to access properties or `[]` to access elements is interpreted as literal characters.

So in this case, you can use the second option (don't surround it in quotes) if the result of the lookup is already a string or can be coerced into one.

In the general sense, the first option uses `$(...)` which is a sub-expression. The `...` can be any code, including entire pipelines and function calls and such.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks briantist!
Couldn't seem to find the solution on Google, thanks for your quick answer!